# THREE.JS how to move the bones of a SkinnedMesh?

Tags: animation, three.js, mesh

I'm working on a 3D project using THREE.JS and I want to animate a simple minecraft like character.

To do so, I exported one from Blender (with bones) and I render it with THREE.JS using the SkinnedMesh class.

I tried everything to make the arm of the mesh to move but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried changing rotation, position, matrix and also setting all flag to true (like  matrixWorldNeedsUpdate but the arm did not move).

Here is a sample code:

```
var meshBody = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, materialTexture );

...

animate = function(){
    meshBody.bones[3].rotation.z += 0.1     
    meshBody.bones[3].matrixAutoUpdate = true;
    meshBody.bones[3].matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While constructing your mesh, make sure the skinning property of your material is set to `true`, e.g.:

```
mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh (geometry, 
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({color: 0xaaaa00, skinning: true})
     );
```

Comment: Hmm, when I do this the model disappears. 
On this tutorial [link](https://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/) it mentions naming the bones with the same as vertex groups. Sounds a bit weird but I tried it and it made no difference...

Comment: Okay I got it now. I need to add more than one vertex.

Comment: @robshearing If you found a solution, can you answer my question ? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036248/how-to-manipulate-individual-bones-of-a-3d-model-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

It uses quaternion rotations by default. Try to set `meshBody.bones[i].useQuaternion = false;` and then change rotation's params or use [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) instead.