# How to manipulate individual bones of a 3d model in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, 3d-model, pose

I would like to display a 3d model of a skeleton (human body), using React Native.

Then if I would like to set the position of specific bones of the human body, I would like to call a function like:

```
setPosition(3dmodelObject,boneId,yaw,pitch roll);
```

or

```
setPosition(3dmodelObject,boneId,w,x,y,z); // If using quaternion
```

example:

```
   setPosition(myHumanSkeleton,foreArmId,30,45,70);
   setPosition(myDogSkeleton,tailId,12,40,40);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can get started ?

I've noticed there are a number of libraries (example: Three.js), but I can't seem to tell if any of them allow me to select individual bones of a 3d model, and set its orientation using an euler angle, or quaternion.

Answer (score 2):

[Three.js](https://threejs.org/) is the traditional JS-based 3D-rendering engine of choice (since its debut in 2010 anyway). Its documentation shows that it supports both [Euler angles](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler) and [quaternions](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion).

Here is a runnable example of both in use in a React app:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const eulerForGreenCube = new THREE.Euler(1, 2, 3, 'XYZ');
    const quaternionForBlueCube = new THREE.Quaternion(.5, .2, .7, .5);

    // Scene Setup:

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera.position.z = 12;

    // Shapes:

    {
      const cubeSize = 4;
      const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
      const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 'green'
      });
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
      mesh.position.set(5, 5, 0);
      mesh.setRotationFromEuler(eulerForGreenCube);
      scene.add(mesh);
    } {
      const cubeSize = 4;
      const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
      const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 'blue'
      });
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
      mesh.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
      mesh.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternionForBlueCube);
      scene.add(mesh);
    }

    // Lights:

    {
      const light1 = new THREE.PointLight('white', 2, 20, 2);
      scene.add(light1);
    } {
      const light2 = new THREE.HemisphereLight('white', 'red', 1);
      scene.add(light2);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref = {
      ref => (this.mount = ref)
    }
    />;
  }
}

//const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

If you are looking for a good alternative to Three.js that is still pure-JS-based, [Babylon.js](https://www.babylonjs.com/) is the other option I'm aware of. First released in 2013, it has recently gained favor among many circles. [This Slant list of user-preferred options](https://www.slant.co/topics/3777/~best-open-source-javascript-3d-engines), for example, shows Babylon.js firmly in the top spot. Babylon.js's documentation also shows that it supports both [Euler angles and quaternions](https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/rotation_conventions).

A third option to consider if you don't mind building your 3D models outside of JS and importing them as GLTF2 or OBJ models is Facebook's own [React 360](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/) library. It's worth noting that React 360 actually ["relies on Three.js for some of its rendering work"](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/objects.html). React 360's documentation shows [how you can use it to work with 3D objects](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/objects.html). You can see examples of setting Euler angles in the [Flat Surfaces section](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/surfaces.html#flat-surface). This page also mentions that you can "pass in a Quaternion of camera to re-center the surface on the user's viewport", but does not specifically say if you can set object angles with quaternions.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply! I still don’t see how to manipulate individual bones of a skeleton though. The docs show how to manipulate a rendered object, but not a skeleton loaded from an obj file or something (I couldn’t find an example). Any idea? By skeleton I’m referring to the kind used in anatomy classes.

Comment: Ah gotcha, didn't realize you were planning on pulling the bone objects in from an external file. I unfortunately don't have time to give a detailed example meeting those requirements, but my general recommendation would be to start with a skeleton that has each bone as a separate object (like this one: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/character/anatomy/3d-human-skeleton) and then use the methods I mentioned with any of the 3 libraries to manipulate them as needed.

Comment: React 360 works exclusively with 3D models from external files, so the methods I linked to should work for your needs. In Three.js, you should be able to pull in the bones as objects using one of the loaders (e.g., OBJLoader: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader) and then use the methods I mentioned to rotate them as needed. More details on using the loaders can be found here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: I see how to load the model, but not how to access and manipulate individual bones at run time.

Comment: Any idea how to manipulate individual bones of a model loaded at run time ?